# Understanding "implicit block" as seen in Prawn

Tags: ruby, block, prawn

In Prawn pdf example by prawn http://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf the manual references extensively using "implicit blocks". I have never been able to get this to work with Prawn or any Ruby code for that matter. I get this error NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for main:Object

```
# Assignment
pdf = Prawn::Document.new
pdf.text "Hello World"
pdf.render_file "assignment.pdf"
# Implicit Block
Prawn::Document.generate("implicit.pdf") do
 text "Hello World"
end
# Explicit Block
Prawn::Document.generate("explicit.pdf") do |pdf|
 pdf.text "Hello World"
end
```

Can anyone explain either what I am doing wrong or better yet, what exactly is meant by an implicit block? It seems time saving but I am unable to find documentation on this type of "implicit block" anywhere.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Your code, with a `require 'prawn'` at the top works perfectly for me?

Comment: If adding require 'prawn' allows the implicit block to work then the manual is missing that information. I am a bit surprised though as the way the manual is written, it would seem that ruby inherently works as shown after declaring a new prawn document. I am used to developers providing rough manuals at best but I kind of didn't expect this from a 107 page manual. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I added an example that I hope provides a little more clarity on how they're using implicit & explicit blocks & they're treated/handled separately

Comment: It wasn't that adding the require made it work, I wasn't clear on your original question and the examples it shows aren't the clearest. Your error method about `foo` doesn't reference anything. If you can post an actual code sample that will help debug

Comment: "Implicit block" is not a thing in Ruby. It was used here as a shortcut for "block with an implicit receiver", where `self` has been set to the PDF object (so that `text` calls `self.text`), In the "explicit block" version, `self` has not been modified, so Prawn's methods will need an explicit receiver (`pdf.text`) that has been provided as the parameter to the block (`|pdf|`).

Comment: I suppose what my question really boils down to is this;
states is a nested array of states and state abbreviations.
states.each do include? "DE" end throws a undefined method `include?' for main:Object error
states.each do |foo| foo.include? "DE" end works just fine. Why?

Comment: Because `Prawn::Document#initialize` (and by extension, `::generate` which calls it) [checks how many parameters the block has ("arity") and then does different things depending on the result](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/blob/6637218ab17898d357d150ffe1562b8903df7e96/lib/prawn/document.rb#L238), while `Array#each` always does the same thing. Facing the risk of sounding repetitive, there is no such thing as "implicit block" in Ruby, and you can't generalise this behaviour. `Prawn::Document.generate` behaves that way because it was _programmed to do so_.

Comment: @Amadan make this is answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in my comment, your code works nearly perfectly, out of the box.

The source provides some examples about usage, such as [here](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/blob/master/lib/prawn/document.rb#L124-L141), but the actual difference in usage isn't actually clear there until you dig into the details and try out some examples.

You can see the difference in how this works as a closure in the example below. The only changes I made:

- Used an instance variable, `@content` as an example of what you might use in an actual application
- Added the instance var to the implicit version
- Removed the comments

Example:

```
require 'prawn'

@content = "Hello World"

Prawn::Document.generate "example1.pdf" do
  # self here is set to the newly instantiated Prawn::Document
  # and so any variables in the outside scope are unavailable
  font "Times-Roman"
  draw_text @content, :at => [200,720], :size => 32
end

Prawn::Document.generate "example2.pdf" do |pdf|
  # self here is left alone
  pdf.font "Times-Roman"
  pdf.draw_text @content, :at => [200,720], :size => 32
end
```

You'll note that the example1.pdf file doesn't contain the text because the outside scope is unavailable. Example2.pdf does contain the text.

Note this works just fine with the local variable settings noted in the examples (e.g. you can set `content = 'hello'` outside of the blocks and it works just fine)